# There is a way to set entities dynamically based on model string name in odata asp net core web api?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am trying to register entities dynamically in `odata` based  on `string name` or `variable types`.

```
var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            modelBuilder.EntitySet<Employee>("Employees");
            modelBuilder.EntitySet<Manager>("Managers");
```

I am using this way but trying to find dynamic one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection to achieve, For example register "empolyee" with entityName string variable:

```
string entityName = "Employee";
```

After create modelbuilder, use the following code to execute `modelBuilder.EntitySet<Employee>("Employees");` with Reflection.

```
Type entityType = Type.GetType($"EmployeeNamespace.{entityName}");
var entitySetMethod = typeof(ODataConventionModelBuilder).GetMethod("EntitySet");
var genericEntitySetMethod = entitySetMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);
genericEntitySetMethod.Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { entityName });
```

Comment: i am getting System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity set 'Employees' is based on type 'WebApplication1.Models.Employee' that has no keys defined.'.. and even when i put the key using HasKey method and reflection, it runs but it gives me only the key when i get data. note that there and Id property with [key] annotation.

Comment: I was using a wrong modelBuidlder class, the right one is ODataConventionModelBuilder. thank you Jerry!